# Keeping links in SimplePie description

Tags: html, tags, strip, simplepie

I am using SimplePie to feed blog entries to a non-Wordpress website. By default it strips out all  HTML tags, but there is a way to keep them in, by inserting this code near the top of your page:

```
$feed->strip_htmltags(false);
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();
```

However this doesn't seem to be working. The links are present in my feed reader, so I don't believe the problem is with the feed itself, rather with the way I'm using SimplePie. Has anyone else encountered this issue, and found a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> By default it strips out all HTML tags

Actually, [it uses a blacklist](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/strip_htmltags) to strip certain tags, but it does not strip links (`a` elements). If links are not appearing, then likely you're accessing the content wrong, or something else is stripping them.

One possibility for why this is occurring is that you're accessing the [summary](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_description) of the item instead of the [content](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_content).